# MySQL sorting data with trigger to other tables - resolved

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have main_table:
SELECT PORT_ID, DATA from main_table

i need run trigger AFTER INSERT main_table which sort DATA to the other tables:
INSERT INTO @PORT_ID (DATA) VALUE (@DATA)

return an error message:
dynamic sql is not allowed in stored function or trigger resolved.

Any idea?
Many thanks

**Workarround**

I do a simply workarround, 1, save a SQL query into new table as a whole text. 2, run an EVENT per second with EXECUTE saved query

Comment: show please the code of your trigger

Comment: BEGIN        
            SET @IDGPS := (CONCAT('gps_', NEW.PORT));
            
      INSERT INTO @IDGPS (`DATA`) VALUES (NEW.DATTA); 
  END

Comment: This is not allowed for triggers and functions,  you can try to call a stored procedure

Comment: when i run procedure from figger it is same.

Answer (score 0):

This is to big for a comment.

A simple Procedure that only executes the insert as prepared statement

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `procedure_stmt`(IN test TEXT)
BEGIN
SET @sql = test;
 PREPARE stmt2 FROM @sql;
 EXECUTE stmt2;
END
```

ANd as a trigger

```
BEGIN

 SET @sql = CONCAT('INSERT INTO ','gps_', NEW.PORT,' (DATA) VALUES (',NEW.DATTA,')'); 
CALL procedure_stmt(@sql);
 END$$
 DELIMITER ;
```

If you had posted tables and data i would have tested it further.

Comment: that samne result .... MySQL error: Dokumentace

#1336 - Dynamic SQL is not allowed in stored function or trigger